# Efficient Python loop for comparing 2 columns in old and new DataFrame and if they are similar then add to the new DataFrame?

Tags: python, database, dataframe, sorting

So I have to 2 files that I imported as a dataframes. The objective is to compare the columns and if they are like enough then add information from the old dataframe to the new one. I have a general idea and approach of what to do but I think there will be a more efficient way to complete the task.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOJEF.png)

img1 was my first attempt at the problem but it wasn't iterating through the entire data set to find the matches. The data set is approx 1000 in new and 2000 in old.

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDWgy.png)

img2 was my second attempt at the problem. However I starting running into the an indexing issue that I was exceeding the dataframe length.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas series have a `compare()` method. If you then add a `keep_equal = True` argument then the returned data will only keep the rows that are the same. You can then compare with the total length of the Series and then do whatever you want to do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

if df1.Name.compare(df1.FamerName, keep_true=True).shape[0] >= 0.8 * df1.shape[0]:
    if df1.Address.compare(df2.Address, keep_true=True).shape[0] >= 0.8 * df1.shape[0]:
        # do stuff
```

The advantage of this method is that there's no loop, the comparison is vectorised internally.

Comment: The data in the rows are not exactly equal yet have the same meaning. Example: oldData.Address = 1234 muddy county road and the same newData.Address = 1234 Muddy County Road. I should also include that the data is not indexed the same.

Comment: Then use `df.Address.str.lower()` before comparing on both address columns